# How to display the expanded form of an exponential function inserted by user?

Tags: java, math

I am using a for-loop to compute the power of an integer. The user is able to input both:

- int a, which is the integer itself
- int b, which is the power the
  integer

Finally, I am supposed to display the result in expanded form. I am stuck with this step. Can anyone help?

I have tried to have a nested while loop inside the for loop which doesn't seem to work.

```
//power of an integer

//interacting with user
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise2{
    public static void main (String[] args){

        //ready to accept input
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter an integer: ");
            int a = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("What power do you want " + 
                        a + "to be raised to? ");
            int b = input.nextInt();

            int count=2;

        //for loop
        for (int i =1 ; i<=1; i++){

            //output data
            System.out.println((int)Math.pow(a,b));

            }
        }

    }
}
```

The result is a double produced by Math.pow(); which still does not have the expanded form. `e.g.: 4^3 display: 4 x 4 x 4`.

Comment: You have an [off-by-one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) in your loop: `i` starts at 1 and your loop ends if `i` is 1 or larger, hence the loop block is never entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `for` loop is not constructed properly. `for (int i = 1 ; i <= 1; i++)` will only execute the body of the loop *once*.

Here's a solution that prints the first variable `a`, `b` number of times as desired. The program also makes an arbitrary check `b > 0` to ensure that the result can be expressed in an expanded form.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter an integer: ");
    int a = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("What power do you want " + a + " to be raised to? ");
    int b = input.nextInt();

    if (b > 0) {
        System.out.print(a);
        for (int i = 1; i < b; i++)
            System.out.print(" x " + a);
    } else {
        System.out.println(a + "^" + b + " cannot be expanded!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! Did some minor edits and got the answer!
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Exercise2{
 public static void main (String[] args){
  Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter an integer: ");
      int a = input.nextInt();
      System.out.println("What power do you want " + a + "to be raised to? ");
      int b = input.nextInt();

      int answer = (int) Math.pow(a,b);

   System.out.print(a);
   for (int i = 0; i < (b - 1); i++) {
   System.out.print(" x " + a);
   }
   System.out.println(" = " + answer);
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
StringJoiner j = new StringJoiner ("×","","");
for(int i=0; i<b;i++){ 
j.add(a+""); }
System.out.print(j.toString());
```

this code just prints in this form, suppose a=3 b=4, so the output is 3×3×3×3
so then you can have your Math.pow method for the result of your inputs